# PHP Hashtag for arabic can not be a link

Tags: php, hashtag

I have hashtag function like this:

```
$ret = preg_replace('/#(\\w+)/','<span class="tag"><a href=//'.$host.'/hashtag?key=$1>$0</a></span>',$ret);
```

If post like:

```
I like this #verymuch
```

Then the #verymuch will be : http://example.com/hashtag?key=verymuch
and to be a link.
Until this working perfect.

But when I type the arabic hashtag. example:

```
I like #أكل
```

The hashtag #أكل is not to be link.

How can I set it to the arabic language to be link too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use:

```
$ret = preg_replace('/#([^\s]+)/','<span class="tag"><a href=//'.$host.'/hashtag?key=$1>$0</a></span>',$ret);
```

But i think arabic signs in an url will not work.

\w will only match a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character but not arabic signs.

Comment: What difference should that change in the pattern make? Apart from the fact that the capturing is not the issue here...

Comment: I've updated my answer (\w will not match arabic signs).

Comment: Oh, that would be surprising. Do you have any reference for that statement?

Comment: Thre PCRE documentation of PHP is very very bad... If you have a look at the original PCRE docs you will find _"By default, characters whose code points are greater than 127 never match \d, \s, or \w, and always match \D, \S, and \W, although this may vary for characters in the range 128-255 when locale-specific matching is happening."_ I don't know the exact code points of أكل, but i think they are far over 255. http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html

Comment: Please have a try with the modification I posted. :-) Note the "by default" in that statement you posted.

Comment: Thanks. Working perfectly (Y)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working for me with one minor modification:

```
<?php

$host = 'some.host.site';

//$subject = 'I like this #verymuch';
$subject = 'I like this #أكل';
$pattern = '/#(\\w+)/u';
$replace = '<span class="tag"><a href=//'.$host.'/hashtag?key=$1>$0</a></span>';

var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject));
```

The output is:

```
string(90) "I like this <span class="tag"><a href=//some.host.site/hashtag?key=أكل>#أكل</a></span>"
```

Note that I added the `u` modifier to your regex pattern. That switches the regex engine to use unicode mode. Given that the replacement appear to work just fine.